# Spark dataframe.saveAsTable vs. spark.sql("insert overwrite table ...")

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I observed huge performance difference in writing to parquet partitioned table with different calls. See following Scala code example.

```
val df = spark.table("my_parquet_partitioned_table")
df.write.partitionBy("event_date").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("my_table2")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_view")
spark.sqlContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") // necessary for next line. Why saveAsTable doesn't need this?

spark.sql("insert overwrite table my_table3 select * from df_view") // 10
```

10 times slower than saveAsTable.

BTW I was running this on AWS/EMR.

Comment: Maybe you can run `explain()`s on both, and compare to see where the diff is?